# ASP.NET Web Application with multiple database support

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, multiple-databases

We are developing a asp.net web based application, so for example if I want to deploy the same web application with MS access as back end or Sql as back end, the data access layer it should use should be configurable.

If I go with the below architecture

Model

```
Employee
    ID
    Name
```

DAL

```
EmployeeAccessDb (Uses inline queries)
    GetAll
    GetByID
    Insert
    Update
    Delete

EmployeeSqlDb (Uses stored procedures)
    GetAll
    GetByID
    Insert
    Update
    Delete
```

Page (Uses EmployeeAccessDb / EmployeeSqlDb)

```
ObjectDataSource SelectMethod="GetAll" TypeName=" < EmployeeAccessDb / EmployeeSqlDb >"
Insert
Update
Delete
```

So if I use Access as back end the page should use Access DAL and if I use Sql page should use SQL DAL.

Please let me know how can I make this configurable.

Answer (score 1):

please you web.config for configuration and in your DAL read the value form the web.config and make the nessesary call to the database

You'll need to add a reference to System.Configuration. You should be using the ConfigurationManager

```
    String Activedatabase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDatabase"];
```

web.config will look like this

```
    <appSettings>
     <add key="ActiveDatabase" value="SQLDB"/>
    </appSettings>
```